# Не работает функция destroy на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def python_checkbutton1 (event):
    destroy_object = [python_checkbutton2, python_checkbutton3, python_checkbutton4, python_checkbutton5]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()
def python_checkbutton2 (event):
    destroy_object = [python_checkbutton1, python_checkbutton3, python_checkbutton4, python_checkbutton5]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()

def python_checkbutton3 (event):
    destroy_object = [python_checkbutton2, python_checkbutton1, python_checkbutton4, python_checkbutton5]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()

def python_checkbutton4 (event):
    destroy_object = [python_checkbutton2, python_checkbutton3, python_checkbutton1, python_checkbutton5]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()

def python_checkbutton5 (event):
    destroy_object = [python_checkbutton1, python_checkbutton2, python_checkbutton3, python_checkbutton4]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("")
root.geometry("300x250")

header = Label(text="Choose number", padx=15, pady=10)
header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

lang = IntVar()

python_checkbutton1 = Radiobutton(text="№1", value="1", variable=lang, padx=15, pady=10)
python_checkbutton1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

python_checkbutton2 = Radiobutton(text="№2", value="2", variable=lang, padx=15, pady=10)
python_checkbutton2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

python_checkbutton3 = Radiobutton(text="№3", value="3", variable=lang, padx=15, pady=10)
python_checkbutton3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

python_checkbutton4 = Radiobutton(text="№4", value="4", variable=lang, padx=15, pady=10)
python_checkbutton4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

python_checkbutton5 = Radiobutton(text="№5", value="5", variable=lang, padx=15, pady=10)
python_checkbutton5.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)

selection = Label(textvariable=lang, padx=15, pady=10)
selection.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Мой прокол, вместо delete должен быть destroy

Comment: destroy у вас прописан в функциях, но я не вижу в коде ни одного места, которое могло бы запустить эти самые функции. А если функция не запускается, то и код внутри функции тоже не запускается.

Comment: Что и куда нужно добавить что бы оно заработало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавить опцию command=function в объявление кнопки, и по-моему event в функциях не нужны

```
python_checkbutton1 = Radiobutton(text="№1", value="1", variable=lang,
command=python_checkbutton1, padx=15, pady=10)
```